# How to change StringEdit value in overridden method leave()?

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, x++, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I have a StringEdit and overrided the leave-method.

```
public boolean leave()
{
    boolean ret;
    ;
    info("leaved");
    this.text("leaved");
    CliHouseNumber.text("leaved");
    ret = super();
    info("leaved");

    return ret;
}
```

The problem is that the 2 infologs are fired but the value of CliHouseNumber doesn't change. Why does the value stay the same?

INFO:

- The field is linked to a DataSource and a DataField

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, your correct solution:

Set the DataField property of the edit box to empty, and set the EDT property to the correct type. Otherwise, you are only allowed to set in values that appear in the DataField; anything else you try and set will be rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting

ret = super();

*before* your code; it may be undoing the changes you have made?

Comment: is there a possibility to unlink the StringEdit from the DataSource and DataField to change its value and finally link it again?

Comment: I think it's not possible to change the value of a field if it has a DataSource and a DataField.

Comment: It might not be; I don't know if the system you are using enforces the contents of the edit box from the database, or whether it supports dynamic updates to the underlying data through changes to the edit box. What if the user changes the text in that box? Does it change the underlying data? If so, then maybe the problem is that you are missing a call to fire a notification to update the data... (I don't know Axapta / Dynamics, so I'm only guessing).

Comment: Okay, so I made the DataField-property in that field empty and set the EDT-property to the Type I want. It solved the problem that I had. Because when the DataField was set I could only select the values that are available in that DataField of that DataSource and no random values were allowed. 

Thank you for trying to help me :)

Comment: So if you can post the answer I gave I will accept it as the answer :)

Comment: It's OK, you answered your own question better than I ever could! No point in giving me false credit for a question I couldn't answer {;v)

Comment: No it's not menth to give you false credit. But the problem is solved and I can't accept my own answers :)